# Why does this happen to numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Found this [here](http://blog.glaucus.in/wow-javascript-such-good-conventions-much-sense/):

[image]

How does this even work? What is happening here? Why does the number change in the first line?

Comment: Downvoters should comment.

Comment: JavaScript numbers are binary floating-point values with a limited precision. The first number is larger than the value of the largest exactly-representable integer.

Comment: number is over Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin

Comment: And note that the exact same thing would happen (or, at least, *something* weird would happen) if you tried to use that number as a value in any language using 64-bit IEEE floating point.

Comment: @Hacketo That only answers the last part of my question.

Comment: @GrimbodeI They probably think that the 'question does not show any research effort'. They might even go as far as thinking 'it is unclear or not useful'. That's what a downvote means per the title of the arrow. Why 'demand' a comment? see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question .. "downvote and move on". Not saying I agree or not (didn't vote) but it's certainly not necessary to comment...

Answer (score 3):

> JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point format numbers as specified in IEEE 754 and can only safely represent numbers between -(2<sup>53</sup> - 1) and 2<sup>53</sup> - 1.

The number 111111111111111111 (18 digits) is above that range.

Reference: [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: I think you're onto something here but I take issue with the range :)

Comment: @Pointy Whoops! -(253 - 1) to 253 - 1 wouldn't be very useful at all. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, JavaScript uses the [double-precision 64-bit floating point format](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp) for the numbers. 52 bits are reserved for the values, 11 bits for the exponent and 1 bit for the plus/minus sign.

The whole deal with the numbers is beautifully explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqHDDtVYJRI). Essentially, JavaScript uses a pointer that moves along the 52 bits to mark the floating point. Naturally, you need more bits to express larger numbers such as your 111111111111111111.

To convert your number into the binary, it would be

```
sign - 0
exponent - 10000110111
mantissa - 1000101010111110111101111000010001100000011100011100
```

The more space is taken by the value, the less is available for the decimal digits.

Eventually, simple calculations such as the increment by 1 will become inaccurate due to the lack of bits on the far right and the lowest possible increment will depend on the position of your pointer.